# Turn off Hard Drives via Powershell

Tags: powershell, hard-drive

I want to write a script.
This script needs to turn off the hard drive, reboot, and then i want to check if the drive is mounted. 
Is there a powershell commandlet to turn off the hard drive instantly?
The rest of my script is already finished.

```
if($(Get-PSDrive).Name -contains 'E')
{
    sleep -Seconds 100
    cd e: 
    echo $null > "$(date -Format "dd-MM-yy--hh-mm-ss").txt"
    $f = $(dir).Length
    c:
    cd C:\Users\Joel\Desktop 
    remove-item *
    echo $null > $f
    if($f -lt 100){
      Restart-Computer 
    }
}
else {

echo $date "Drive E not available" >> C:\Users\Joel\Desktop\not-available.txt

}
```

Comment: Care to define what you mean by "turn off?"

Comment: i want to simulate a cold start. like i turned off my PC and switched off the power. then turn on again. 
I want to test if the drive is damaged. I noticed, that the drive is not mounted at any start. Now i want to simulate a kind of stress test

Comment: Unmounting the drive will not power it down. I'm not sure how the OS puts spin drives to sleep, but I would guess it happens at the driver layer (ie, at a ring well below where your powershell script is running).

Comment: in windows just we can remove path of drive , when you remove path can not explore that !